# BIND cannot map one name

Tags: dns, bind

I setup a BIND server. Let domain be `example.com`, `httpd` running.
There is a separate zone for aliases to another domain, `different.com`

I setup zone file for `different.com` to be:

`am     IN    CNAME   example.com.`
`bm     IN    CNAME   example.com.`
`cm     IN    CNAME   example.com.`
`dm     IN    CNAME   example.com.`
`em     IN    CNAME   example.com.`

Reconfigured only host name.

Zone transfer was done. Only 4 of 5 works, `am, bm, dm, em`, but `cm` do not.
Is `cm` a special BIND keyword? What can I check? Can there be a restriction for CNAME number for a domain?

Comment: Make sure that either the origin is `.` or that you end each name with a `.`

Comment: They are, I forgot to add them here, sorry.

Comment: The same goes for the names in front... perhaps include any ORIGIN lines. `cm` does not occur anywhere else? Did you try to use `cm` before adding it, in which case you may have to wait out the negative caching time.

Comment: Ok, we found the solution (@wurtel was right too): BIND cache had old zones despite serial updates. Flushing the cache helped; also, use dig, it is way better tool than host --- it will give you a zone serial for example, so you will know from which version the answer is coming from!